# Abrir modal en iteración con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy iterando unos resultados de una consulta con AJAX y estoy haciendo un `for` para iterar todos los que hay.

```
success: function (resultado){
     $.each(resultado , function(index, productos) { 
        for(i = 0; i < productos.length; i++){
           if(idCategoria == 6) {
               $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="lasCat seleccionProducto center" data-id="'+ productos[i].id +'">\
                   <a href="#'+ productos[i].slug +'" class="abrModal" data-user="'+ productos[i].slug +'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'+ productos[i].slug +'" id="#'+ productos[i].slug +'">\
                   <img src="'+ productos[i].foto +'" alt="" class="img-fluid">\
                   <h2>'+ productos[i].name +'</h2>\
                   </a>\
                  </div>');
                                

                  $('.seleccionProducto').on('click',function () {
                     var prod = $(this).data("id");
                     var url = '/ficha-producto-pizza';
                     $.ajax({
                        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                        type: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        data: {'prod': prod},
                        success: function (elProducto){
                            $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="modal left modalLat" id="'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";>\
                                <div class="modal-dialog myModal" role="document">\
                                    <div class="modal-content">\
                                        <a class="cerrar_modal_lateral"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>\
                                           <h2>'+ elProducto.producto.name +'</h2>\
                                        </div>\
                                     </div>\
                                 </div>')
                                },
                             });
                             abreMenu();
                            });   
                        } 
                    }
                });
            },
```

Y luego tengo la función `abreMenu();` para que me desplegue el modal lateral.

```
function abreMenu() {
        var menuLateral = true;
        $('.abrModal').click(function(){
            $('.myModal').animate({ width:'640px' });
            menuLateral=false;
        });
        $('.cerrar_modal_lateral').click(function(){
            $('.myModal').animate({ width:'0px' });
            $('.modalLat').modal('hide');//ocultamos el modal
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');//eliminamos la clase del body para poder hacer scroll
            menuLateral=true;
        });
    };
```

Pero lo que pasa es que itera dos productos el resultado primero del AJAX, eso está bien por que hay dos, pero cuando pulso a el producto para que se abra el modal, tengo que pulsar justo dos veces, como si fuese la cantidad de ciclos que hay, luego una vez que para abrir he pulsado dos veces en cada uno de los dos, ya se abre a la primera, peor si abro dos veces el mismo se genera un gran retraso en que aparezca el modal, seguramente estoy haciendo muchas cosas mal.

Comment: ingresales un evento onClick  a cada producto,asi puedes identificar cada click por individual

Comment: Intenta sacar el `click` afuera del `for`

Comment: Estás llamando a abreMenu dentro del bucle, con lo que por cada elemento que se añade al DOM con la clase `abrModal` estás añadiendo un event listener a TODOS los elementos con dicha clase. Si añadieras 4 elementos tendrías 4 listeners para el primero, 3 para el segundo, 2 para el tercero y uno para el cuarto elemento añadido. Deberías llamar al método abreMenu una única vez, después de generar todos los elementos

Comment: Buenas @PabloLozano he sacado el evento `click del for pero me sigue pasando igual tengo que hacer click dos veces aparentemente por que hay dos productos, no entiendo muy bien lo que puedo hacer

Comment: usa delegacion de eventos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publico la solución que le he dado al problema.

```
success: function (resultado){
                // No modifiques el hash el enlace lo actualizó
                $.each(resultado , function(index, productos) { 
                    for(i = 0; i < productos.length; i++){
                        //Comprobamos que id de categoria viene
                        //Si es 6 = (pizza) mostramos otra pantalla diferente
                        if(idCategoria == 6) {
                            $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="lasCat seleccionProducto center" data-id="'+ productos[i].id +'">\
                                <a class="abrModal">\
                                    <img src="'+ productos[i].foto +'" alt="" class="img-fluid">\
                                    <h2>'+ productos[i].name +'</h2>\
                                </a>\
                                </div>');
                             
                         
                        } 
                    }                    
                });
            },
```

He sacado del `success` y del `for` el click para desplegar el modal, tambien elimino del `href` las funciones para que abra el modal. Una vez hecho eso creo una función nueva.

```
$('#zonaProductos').on( 'click', '.seleccionProducto', function(){
        var prod = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var url = '/ficha-producto-pizza';
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: {'prod': prod},
            success: function (elProducto){
                $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="modal left modalLat" id="'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";>\
                    <div class="modal-dialog myModal" role="document">\
                        <div class="modal-content">\
                            <a class="cerrar_modal_lateral"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>\
                            <h2>'+ elProducto.producto.name +'</h2>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>')
                //Una vez cargado el modal, ya podemos hacer click en el botón de mostrar
                $("#" + elProducto.producto.slug +"").modal("show");
                //Llamamos a la función para darle ancho a la ventana de modal
                abreMenu(); 
            },
        });
        //abreMenu();
    });
```

En esta función escucho a través de una función `click` cual es el `data-id` del producto que le estoy haciendo click, una vez generada la ventana modal ya añado que se desplegue `$("#" + elProducto.producto.slug +"").modal("show");` y ya una vez se va a desplegar llamo a la función `abreMenu();` .

También la función `abreMenu()` he tenido que cambiar cosas.

```
function abreMenu() {
  var menuLateral = true;
        
  $('.myModal').animate({ width:'640px' });
    menuLateral=false;
        
  $('.cerrar_modal_lateral').click(function(){
    $('.myModal').animate({ width:'0px' });
    $('.modalLat').modal('hide');//ocultamos el modal
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');//eliminamos la clase del body para poder hacer scroll
    menuLateral=true;
   });
};
```

He quitado el evento click `$('.abrModal').click(function(){` por que ya lo estoy abriendo desde el success.

No se si es la mejor forma en la que lo he arreglado pero funciona bien.